# How to plot multiple sunburst plotly plots into one figure?

Tags: r, plotly

Considering the example from https://plotly.com/r/sunburst-charts/ it is possible to plot multiple sunburst plots into one figure:

```
library(plotly)
d1 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/coffee-flavors.csv')
d2 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/718417069ead87650b90472464c7565dc8c2cb1c/sunburst-coffee-flavors-complete.csv')
fig <- plot_ly() 
fig <- fig %>%
  add_trace(
    ids = d1$ids,
    labels = d1$labels,
    parents = d1$parents,
    type = 'sunburst',
    maxdepth = 2,
    domain = list(column = 0)
    ) 
fig <- fig %>%
  add_trace(
    ids = d2$ids,
    labels = d2$labels,
    parents = d2$parents,
    type = 'sunburst',
    maxdepth = 3,
    domain = list(column = 1)
  ) 
fig <- fig %>%
    layout(
      grid = list(columns =2, rows = 1),
      margin = list(l = 0, r = 0, b = 0, t = 0),
      sunburstcolorway = c(
        "#636efa","#EF553B","#00cc96","#ab63fa","#19d3f3",
        "#e763fa", "#FECB52","#FFA15A","#FF6692","#B6E880"
      ),
      extendsunburstcolors = TRUE)
fig
```

I have the problem that I produce different sunburst plots in isolated functions, which I want to plot into one figure subsequently. However, this (as well as `plotly::subplot(p,p)`) does not seem to work:

```
p <- plot_ly(
  labels = c("Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"),
  parents = c("", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve"),
  values = c(10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4),
  type = 'sunburst'
)

fig <- plot_ly() 
fig <- fig %>%
  add_trace(
    p,
    domain = list(column = 0)
  ) 
fig <- fig %>%
  add_trace(
    p,
    domain = list(column = 1)
  ) 
fig <- fig %>%
  layout(
    grid = list(columns =2, rows = 1),
    margin = list(l = 0, r = 0, b = 0, t = 0))
fig
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1867)